# <null> reading from sqlite

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

ok..so i'm reading from an sqlite db data into a string...it works..but when the data is null there is a problem

```
NSLog(@"%@",string);
if(string!=NULL && [string length]!=0){ do stuff }
```

note that the NSLog output is `<null>` not `NULL` or `nil` and i think here is the problem...i'm trying to check for `NULL` when the string is `<null>`

does that make sence?

in any case...is there any way to check if the string is `<null>`? or is there a better way to check for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<null>` is what the `description` method on `NSNull` prints out. You should also check for `string != [NSNull null]`.

(`NSNull` is a placeholder singleton for collections, where actual `nil` values aren't allowed.)

Comment: thank you..it works but there are 2 warnings :`Comparson of distinct pointer types (NSString and NSNull)` and `Comparasion of distinct Objective-C types 'struct NSNull*'and 'struct NSString*'lacks a cast`  any ideas about that?

Comment: Oh, you can just cast: `string != (id)[NSNull null]`. You won't be performing any string methods on it if it's `[NSNull null]`.